# How to listen what were clicked in the test?

Tags: java, selenium, event-handling, webdriver

i try to log click events, but

Example:

button in page object class:

```
  public WebElement btnClear() {
  return driver.findElement(By.name("filter:P_ClearButtonDFID"));
 }
```

click in the test

```
searchPage.btnClear().click();
```

Listner logging:

```
Clicked on: [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (1cf610ba-607c-40a2-94bc-745f1e564bde)] -> name: filter:P_ClearButtonDFID]
```

click Listener:

```
public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {            
    System.out.println("clicked on: " + element.toString());
}
```

as i want:

```
"Clicked: btnClear()" or "Clicked: btnClear"
```

Is it possible to implement?
I don't need log element locator, because some times it has unreadable name, i need log my own name for page object element

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ( considering you are using WebDriverEventListner interface)

```
public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {            
    System.out.println("clicked on: " + element.getAttribute("name"));
}
```

OR

```
public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {            
    System.out.println("clicked on: " + element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: as i said before i don't need log LOCATOR or it attributes.
i need log  name for page object element
btnClear

Comment: Try reflection like element.getClass();

Answer (score 0):

What i meant:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.IsElementPresent;

public class WebElem extends RemoteWebElement {
    private WebElement  element;
    private String      calleeMethod;
    private String      tascase;
    private Logger      logger;

    public WebElem(WebElement elem) {
        element = elem;
        Throwable t = new Throwable();
        StackTraceElement[] elements = t.getStackTrace();
        calleeMethod = elements[1].getMethodName();
        tascase = elements[2].getClassName();

    }

    @Override
    public void click() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(tascase);
        if (IsElementPresent() == true) {
            if (element.isEnabled() == false) {
                logger.info("element " + calleeMethod + " is disabled.");
            } else {
                element.click();
                logger.info("clicked: " + calleeMethod);
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("element " + calleeMethod + " is not found.");
        }

    }

    public void sendKeys(String string) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(tascase);
        if (IsElementPresent() == true) {
        }
        if (element.isEnabled() == false) {
            logger.error("element " + calleeMethod + " is disabled.");
        } else {
            element.sendKeys(string);
            logger.info("Sending keys: " + string + " to: " + calleeMethod);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        element.clear();
    }

    private boolean IsElementPresent() {
        if (element != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

and Report has needed values:

```
Sending keys: 200006862315 to: fldAccountIdFrom
clicked: btnInvoice
clicked: btnResource
```